# Some permalinks work after changing them in adminpanel and database on localhost and other don't

Tags: wordpress, localhost, permalinks

I managed to set up my live wordpress site on my localmachine and also set my home and site url links in the local database. I also set my permalinks back to default in the admin panel but some permalinks are pointing local and others are still pointing to the live site. What could be the isse..?

Answer (score 0):

After making any permalink changes, make sure you go back and save permalink settings. That should refresh all your permalinks and link to their correct addresses.